# How to raise an event in a test that uses Moq?

Tags: unit-testing, events, moq

Here is part of code implementation in parent class:

```
handler.FooUpdateDelegate += FooUpdate(OnFooUpdate);
protected abstract void OnFooUpdate(ref IBoo boo, string s);
```

I have in test method mocked handler:

```
Mock<IHandler> mHandler = mockFactory.Create<IHandler>();
```

This...

```
mHandler.Raise(x => x.FooUpdateDelegate += null, boo, s);
```

...is not working. It says:

> System.ArgumentException : Could not locate event for attach or detach method Void set_FooUpdateDelegate(FooUpdate).

I want to raise `OnFooUpdate` so it triggers the code to be tested in child class.

**Question:** How can I raise delegate (not common event handler) with Moq?

If I missed the point completely, please enligten me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to raise a delegate rather than an event. Is this so?

Is your code along the lines of this?

```
public delegate void FooUpdateDelegate(ref int first, string second);

public class MyClass {
    public FooUpdateDelegate FooUpdateDelegate { get; set; }
}

public class MyWrapperClass {

    public MyWrapperClass(MyClass myclass) {
        myclass.FooUpdateDelegate += HandleFooUpdate;
    }

    public string Output { get; private set; }

    private void HandleFooUpdate(ref int i, string s) {
            Output = s;
    }

}
```

If so, then you can directly invoke the myClass FooUpdateDelegate like so

```
[TestMethod]
public void MockingNonStandardDelegate() {

    var mockMyClass = new Mock<MyClass>();
    var wrapper = new MyWrapperClass(mockMyClass.Object);

    int z = 19;
    mockMyClass.Object.FooUpdateDelegate(ref z, "ABC");

    Assert.AreEqual("ABC", wrapper.Output);

}
```

EDIT: Adding version using interface

```
public interface IMyClass
{
    FooUpdateDelegate FooUpdateDelegate { get; set; }
}    

public class MyClass : IMyClass {
    public FooUpdateDelegate FooUpdateDelegate { get; set; }
}

public class MyWrapperClass {

    public MyWrapperClass(IMyClass myclass) {
        myclass.FooUpdateDelegate += HandleFooUpdate;
    }

    public string Output { get; private set; }

    private void HandleFooUpdate(ref int i, string s) {
            Output = s;
    }

}


[TestMethod]
public void MockingNonStandardDelegate()
{

   var mockMyClass = new Mock<IMyClass>();
   // Test fails with a Null Reference exception if we do not set up
   //  the delegate property. 
   // Can also use 
   //  mockMyClass.SetupProperty(m => m.FooUpdateDelegate);

   mockMyClass.SetupAllProperties();

   var wrapper = new MyWrapperClass(mockMyClass.Object);

   int z = 19;
   mockMyClass.Object.FooUpdateDelegate(ref z, "ABC");

   Assert.AreEqual("ABC", wrapper.Output);

}
```

Comment: Great answer.  One thing I'd mention is that you may have to persist FooUpdateDelegate property, by calling mockMyClass.SetupAllProperties()

Comment: @Eternal21 The Mock<MyClass> is using the concrete implementation of the property from MyClass, so it runs fine as is. If we were mocking an interface (say, IMyClass), then there would be no concrete implementation and setting up the property on the mock would be needed.

Comment: That was exactly my case.