# How to mock the raising of a delegate on an interface that only has a setter?

Tags: c#, moq

I'm trying to mock an interface using Moq, but I can't see how to do it. The interface looks something like this:

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(int i);

public interface MyInterface
{
    void Method(int i);

    MyDelegate MyDelegate { set; }
}
```

I am testing a component that takes an object with this interface as a dependency. I would like to be able to test an interaction where the delegate is raised when the method is called, but I can't see how to do it. I know this is a slightly strange way to design an interface, but I don't have control over that.

Suppose I have a class like this to test:

```
class SystemUnderTest
{
    int i = 0;

    readonly MyInterface myInterface;

    public SystemUnderTest(MyInterface myInterface)
    {
        this.myInterface = myInterface;
        this.myInterface.MyDelegate = DelegateHandler;
    }

    public int Run(int input)
    {
        this.myInterface.Method(input);
        return i;
    }

    void DelegateHandler(int i)
    {
        this.i = i;
    }
}
```

I've tried a test like this, but it gives an exception when setting up the mock. "ArgumentException: Could not locate event for attach or detach method Void set_MyDelegate(ConsoleApp1.MyDelegate)."

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Arrange
    Mock<MyInterface> mock = new Mock<MyInterface>();

    mock
        .Setup(m => m.Method(It.IsAny<int>()))
        .Raises(m => m.MyDelegate = null, 5);

    // Act
    var sut = new SystemUnderTest(mock.Object);
    var result = sut.Run(5);

    // Assert
    Trace.Assert(result == 5);
}
```

Comment: This may be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108772/how-to-raise-an-event-in-a-test-that-uses-moq

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could so to say bridge your `SystemUnderTest.DelegateHandler` through a `MyDelegate` local variable. Try something like this:

```
MyDelegate del = null;

var mock = new Mock<MyInterface>();
mock.SetupSet(m => m.MyDelegate = It.IsAny<MyDelegate>())
    .Callback<MyDelegate>(d => del = d);
mock.Setup(m => m.Method(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .Callback<int>(i => del.Invoke(i));
```

Then actually your `SystemUnderTest.DelegateHandler` method will be called every time you invoke `mock.Method`.

Comment: Is it not more natural to just say `MyDelegate del = null;` where you declare the variable (first line). Other than that I agree with your solution; use `SetupSet` for a set-only property. The fact that the property has a delegate type is not really important. A property (here declared in `MyInterface`) is _not_ an event if it does not have the C# `event` keyword; the asker's use of `Raises` was wrong, but `Callback` is what he wants.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen yap, it can be also `MyDelegate del = null;`, even better to avoid hidden invocation if for some reason `del` has not been setup...

Answer (score 2):

I think the fundamental flaw in your approach is you're trying to mock something that doesn't actually occur in your code - namely that calling the `void Method(int i)` subsequently calls your delegate.  You can't use `Raises` as that's for events.

I think you need a "stub" implementation of `MyInterface`, and you don't need to use Moq at all.  Here's my code that passes the assertion:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Arrange
            var stub = new StubOfMyInterface();

            // Act
            var sut = new SystemUnderTest(stub);
            var result = sut.Run(5);

            // Assert
            Trace.Assert(result == 5);
        }
    }

    public delegate void MyDelegate(int i);

    public interface MyInterface
    {
        void Method(int i);

        MyDelegate MyDelegate { set; }
    }

    public class StubOfMyInterface : MyInterface
    {
        public void Method(int i)
        {
            MyDelegate?.Invoke(i);
        }

        public MyDelegate MyDelegate { get; set; }
    }

    class SystemUnderTest
    {
        int i = 0;

        readonly MyInterface myInterface;

        public SystemUnderTest(MyInterface myInterface)
        {
            this.myInterface = myInterface;
            this.myInterface.MyDelegate = DelegateHandler;
        }

        public int Run(int input)
        {
            this.myInterface.Method(input);
            return i;
        }

        void DelegateHandler(int i)
        {
            this.i = i;
        }
    }   
}
```